# Incremental refresh - An update is interpreted as an insertion and a deletion, not an actual update

Tags: powerbi

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-premium-incremental-refresh

It is mentioned that: "An update is interpreted as an insertion and a deletion, not an actual update."

1. If store rows in last 1 year is configured. And refresh rows in last 7 days is configured. Then if particular OrderDate value is modified (within last 7 day), then will it insert a new record and delete the old record?
2. If prior to 7 day is modified then how is it handled?
3. Similarly if the row from last 7 days is deleted or the row prior to last 7 days is deleted then how does incremental refresh handle this?

Answer (score 0):

For example, if i have
[image]

The after refresh

[image]

As you see, powerbi split my Data into partition:
1 whole Year (2019)
3 whole Quarter (from 2020)
3 whole Month (2020Q410 - 2020Q412)

I have set the refresh for 1 month, so on subsequent starts it will only load data for the current month - 2020Q412.

AD1) I this case, powerbi remove ALL data from partition and insert ALL (not only new rows from your source or updated rows)
AD2) Power BI do nothing, because change is outside declared range

Comment: Today is 16 Dec 2020. Last 1 year means from 16 Dec 2019 onwards ?